# Mouseover highlights with dynamic CSS spread sheets

Tags: css

I allow my customers to select a custom "theme" color which essentially sets the background color of headers, button colors, and other page elements. However, when it comes to highlights, I'm at a loss how to program for that. Since I don't know what the color is coming in, how do I set rollover highlights a couple of shades lighter on mouseover?

For eg: 
Color sets theme color to red. On mouseover on a button, I want to set it to pink. 
Color sets theme color to blue. On mouseover, I want to set it to light blue.

Is there a css rule for doing a highlight that is a % lighter or some lighter version of the base color?

I can't use opacity b/c it changes the link text as well:

```
    <style>
.highlight{background-color:red; opacity:1;}
.highlight:hover{background-color:red; opacity:.5;}
</style>


    <ul>
        <li class="highlight" style="display:block;height:100px;width:100px;">
            hi
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: are you open to jquery? cause i know you can accomplish this with some js. whereas with css, im at a loss with the variability aspect of your theme selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me pretty well and its fairly simple, hope it be resolve your issue and will be useful for you too.

You can use CSS property **Opacity**

```
.highlight{background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.9); }
.highlight:hover{background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.4); }
```

Comment: Yeah I can't use opacity as it affects everything within the tag.

Comment: you can try something like this I have updated the code in my answer, it will only make background-color transparent, not everything in the tag, let me know if it works for you, Thanks

Comment: The problem is I wont know its red coming in. Basically i have to take an unknown color hex and make it lighter. I guess I could convert the hex into rgba and do it that way?

Comment: Exactly, hex in rgba can be converted and used

Answer (score 0):

i know you didnt ask for jquery, but perhaps this solution would interest you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.color').click(function() {
     var r = $(this).attr('r');
        var g = $(this).attr('g');
        var b = $(this).attr('b');
        $('.highlight').css('background-color', 'rgba('+ r + ','+ g + ','+ b + ', 1)');
        $('.highlight').mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba('+ r + ','+ g + ','+ b + ', 0.5)');
        });
        $('.highlight').mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba('+ r + ','+ g + ','+ b + ', 1)');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
td {
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 5px;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
}
.highlight:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="color" r="0" g="0" b="255">Blue Theme</button>
<button class="color" r="255" g="0" b="0">Red Theme</button>
<button class="color" r="150" g="0" b="255">Purple Theme</button>
<br/><br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
        <td class="highlight">Something here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```